# My App crashes on the splash screen when downloaded from the App Store but works on simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, crash

My app was approved and released from the App Store the other day. It was an update for an app. The app is only available for the iPhone. So when I updated it for my phone, it worked perfect. When I updated it on my iPad it crashes on the splash screen.

The app worked fine before the update on the iPad. Also the new update works great on the phone but not the iPad so I'm confused about what the problem is.

Comment: Hey you ever tested with the Xcode? try to simulate the update with Xcode hocked up.

Comment: Unfortunately no, my iPad is not hooked up as a test device for me. I may just have to test it out through Xcode on my iPad though

Comment: Ha :( 
I had similar problem before. In my case my app didn't works only on iPhone 6 Plus and I found out with the Xcode that optional unwrapping was the problem. The syntax was totally okey and complied successfully but not executed well on the iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: @Andrew It would be helpful if you posted the error along with the relevant code that causes the error.

Comment: @DanielZhang I don't have one at the moment, but I'm going to test the app on my iPad and try to get an error to be returned